# Page numbering in all pages not working

Tags: page-numbering

I am writing a thesis and the numbering appears only in the first page of each chapter. I've read this sometimes happens when you have `\pagestyle{empty}` but that's not my case. How can I have the numbering in all pages?

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  since for most  common document classes, all pages numbered is the default, the document class you are using must have a different default, or there is something in your file that is turning them off.  but you haven't given us enough information.  please make a small compilable example that illustrates the problem, and someone here can surely help -- if you don't find the problem on your own while you are creating the example.

Comment: which class do you use, any MWE can you upload?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there was a stry command that was unnoticed.

Comment: As seen below, the review system is completely messed.

Comment: @Johannes_B You mean "as not seen"? *written from within the review queue :)*